# "no suitable image found" error when using numpy

Tags: python, macos, numpy, osx-lion

I tried to use NumPy in Terminal, but the system gave me an error message like this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/**init**.py",
>   line 137, in 
>       import add_newdocs   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py",
>   line 9, in 
>       from numpy.lib import add_newdoc   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/**init**.py",
>   line 4, in 
>       from type_check import *   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py",
>   line 8, in 
>       import numpy.core.numeric as _nx   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/**init**.py",
>   line 5, in 
>       import multiarray
>
> ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so,
>   2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so:
>   no matching architecture in universal wrapper

How can I fix it? I installed Python 2.7.3 from official source and my machine is running OSX 10.7.4.

Comment: I recommend installing python through homebrew with --universal flag: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python

Comment: @Hayden: the OP obviously as a numpy on the machine (else there wouldn't have found `multiarray.so`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your installation of NumPy is borked somehow: it detects that some of its core libraries (eg, `multiarray.so`) were compiled with a different version of the compiler or for a different architecture.

If you installed NumPy *before* updating your Python to 2.7.3, you have to reinstall it. You could find [precompiled binaries](http://www.scipy.org/Download), but as you've modified the original Python, they may not work for you.

At the same time, compiling NumPy on Mac OS X isn't particularly difficult. There are some environment variables to set beforehand, but otherwise, it's a straightforward process. This [link](http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Mac_OS_X) should give you precious information.