# Python ImportError: file too short (NAOqi framework)

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to use the NAOqi framework from Aldebaran in Python via an import on macOS with High Sierra 10.13.5.
I followed their installation instructions on this site
http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/dev/python/install_guide.html

However when I try to import NAOqi, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/Stanley/Documents/Nao/pynaoqi-python2.7-2.1.4.13-mac64/_allog.so, 2): no suitable image found. Did find:
/Users/Stanley/Documents/Nao/pynaoqi-python2.7-2.1.4.13-mac64/_allog.so:  file too short
```

I'm not sure what "file too short" really means, but the error seems to be related with shared libraries. I found a few issues which had a similiar problem, but couldn't figure out a satisfying solution. You'll find them below.

[Aldebaran forums](https://community.ald.softbankrobotics.com/ja/node/7389)
["no suitable image found" error when using numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629644/no-suitable-image-found-error-when-using-numpy)
["File too short" with Tableau Data Extract API (Python and Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247734/file-too-short-with-tableau-data-extract-api-python-and-linux)

Any help would be appreciated.